# Access solutioninfo.cs and assemblyinfo.cs from within .csproj

Tags: c#, properties, csproj, assemblyinfo

I need to access some information from my solutioninfo.cs and assemblyinfo.cs within my .csproj file and use it as a property.

use the value of

```
// my solutioninfo.cs    
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("MyCompany")]
```

in my csproj:

```
// my .csproj
<PublisherName>MyCompany</PublisherName>
```

Is there a way to access the values?

Comment: Maybe my descrition was not that clear: I need the info from the *info.cs files. I do not want to update them. I want to use the info within my .csproj file.

Answer (score 2):

At the very end of your csproj file there are two empty MSBuild targets called BeforeBuild and AfterBuild. Those two targets are more or less the replacement of pre- and post-build events. You can add your own script there. I am setting the version in SolutionInfo.cs for instance after getting it from subversion, which is accomplished by using the MSBuild.CommunityTasks:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <FileUpdate
    Files="$(SolutionInfoFile)"
    Regex="(?&lt;ver&gt;assembly: AssemblyVersion\(&quot;).*&quot;"
    ReplacementText="${ver}$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)&quot;" />
  <FileUpdate
    Files="$(SolutionInfoFile)"
    Regex="(?&lt;ver&gt;assembly: AssemblyFileVersion\(&quot;).*&quot;"
    ReplacementText="${ver}$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)&quot;" />
  <FileUpdate
    Files="$(SolutionInfoFile)"
    Regex="(?&lt;ver&gt;assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion\(&quot;).*&quot;"
    ReplacementText="${ver}$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build)&quot;" />
</Target>
```

AFAIR the FileUpdate task with the regular expression is also part of CommunityTasks.

Comment: I would recommend this approach, you can feed properties to the build via the command-line or directly add them to your project.  Then use the pre-build to update the *.cs files you what to contain that information.  I think this will be a lot easier than going the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via Reflection and the AssemblyAttribute classes.  For example:

```
AssemblyCompanyAttribute company =
 (AssemblyCompanyAttribute)AssemblyCompanyAttribute.GetCustomAttribute(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() , typeof
    (AssemblyCompanyAttribute));

Console.Write(company.Company);
```

You may need to add a using System.Reflection; directive to the top of your code.

Comment: My .csproj file is a xml config file. --> no reflections